# How to get skin tone color pixel in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

In my application I m using following way to get red pixel in a image

```
//
//  PixelsAccessAppDelegate.h
//  PixelsAccess
//
//  Created by Fortune1 on 14/04/10.
//  Copyright __MyCompanyName__ 2010. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class clsPixelAccess;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels1;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels2;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels3;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels4;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels5;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels6;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels7;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels8;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels9;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels10;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels11;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels12;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels13;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels14;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels15;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels16;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels17;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels18;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels19;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels20;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels21;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels22;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels23;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels24;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels25;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels26;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels27;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels28;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels29;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels30;
NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels31;

@interface PixelsAccessAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    clsPixelAccess *obj;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
-(IBAction)processImage:(id)sender;

@end

////////////////////
//
//  PixelsAccessAppDelegate.m
//  PixelsAccess
//
//  Created by Fortune1 on 14/04/10.
//  Copyright __MyCompanyName__ 2010. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PixelsAccessAppDelegate.h"
#import "clsPixelAccess.h"

@implementation PixelsAccessAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (IBAction)processImage:(id)sender
{  
    NSUInteger retVal;
    obj = [[clsPixelAccess alloc] init];

    NSInteger imageSend =[obj processImage1:[UIImage imageNamed:@"s.jpg"]];
    NSInteger iamgeCall =[obj getPixelData:retVal];
    NSUInteger *numberOfRedPixels = retVal; 
    //lblPixelCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"There are %d red pixels in the image", numberOfRedPixels];

}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
///////////////

//
//  clsPixelsAccess.h
//  PixelsAccess
//
//  Created by Fortune1 on 14/04/10.
//  Copyright 2010 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface clsPixelAccess : NSObject {

}
-(NSInteger) processImage1: (UIImage*) image;
-(NSInteger)getPixelData:(NSUInteger *)pixelCount;
@end
/////////


//
//  clsPixelsAccess.m
//  PixelsAccess
//
//  Created by Fortune1 on 14/04/10.
//  Copyright 2010 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "clsPixelAccess.h"
#import "PixelsAccessAppDelegate.h"

@implementation clsPixelAccess

struct pixel
{
    //unsigned char r, g, b,a;
    Byte r, g, b, a;
    int count;
};


-(NSInteger)getPixelData:(NSUInteger *)pixelCount
{
    *pixelCount =numberOfRedPixels;
    return 1;

}
// Process the image and return the number of pure red pixels in it.

- (NSInteger) processImage1: (UIImage*) image
{

    // Allocate a buffer big enough to hold all the pixels

    struct pixel* pixels = (struct pixel*) calloc(1, image.size.width * image.size.height * sizeof(struct pixel));
    if (pixels != nil)
    {
        // Create a new bitmap
        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                     (void*) pixels,
                                                     image.size.width,
                                                     image.size.height,
                                                     8,
                                                     image.size.width * 4,
                                                     CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage),
                                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
                                                     );
        //NSLog(@"1=%d, 2=%d, 3=%d", CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image), CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(image),CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image));
        if (context != NULL)
        {
            // Draw the image in the bitmap
            CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage);
            NSUInteger numberOfPixels = image.size.width * image.size.height;
            NSMutableArray *numberOfPixelsArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberOfPixelsArray] autorelease];
            NSLog( @"Pixel data %d", numberOfPixelsArray);

            /*  
             NSMatrix      *newMatrix = [[NSMatrix alloc] 
             initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(138.0f, 85.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
             mode:NSRadioModeMatrix
             prototype:prototypeButtonCell 
             numberOfRows: 

             numberOfColumns:];
             */ 
            while (numberOfPixels > 0)
            {
                if (pixels->r > 0 && pixels->r <= 7)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data %d",numberOfRedPixels);

                if (pixels->r >= 8 && pixels->r <= 15)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels1++;
                }

                NSLog( @"Red pixel data1 %d",numberOfRedPixels1);

                if (pixels->r >= 16 && pixels->r <=23 )
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels2++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data2 %d",numberOfRedPixels2);

                if (pixels->r >= 24 && pixels->r <=31 )
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels3++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data3 %d",numberOfRedPixels3);

                if (pixels->r >= 32 && pixels->r <= 39)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels4++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data4 %d",numberOfRedPixels4);

                if (pixels->r >= 40 && pixels->r <= 47)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels5++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data5 %d",numberOfRedPixels5);
                if (pixels->r >= 48 && pixels->r <= 55)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels6++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data6 %d",numberOfRedPixels6);

                if(pixels->r >= 56 && pixels->r <= 63)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels7++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data7 %d",numberOfRedPixels7);

                if (pixels->r >= 64 && pixels->r <= 71)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels8++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data8 %d",numberOfRedPixels8);

                if (pixels->r >=  72 && pixels->r <= 79)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels9++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data9 %d",numberOfRedPixels9);

                if (pixels->r >= 80 && pixels->r <= 87)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels10++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data10 %d",numberOfRedPixels10);

                if (pixels->r >= 88 && pixels->r <= 95)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels11++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data11 %d",numberOfRedPixels11);

                if (pixels->r >= 96 && pixels->r <= 103)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels12++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data12 %d",numberOfRedPixels12);

                if (pixels->r >= 104  && pixels->r <= 111)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels13++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data13 %d",numberOfRedPixels13);

                if (pixels->r >= 112 && pixels->r <= 119)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels14++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data14 %d",numberOfRedPixels14);

                if (pixels->r >= 120 && pixels->r <= 127)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels15++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data15 %d",numberOfRedPixels15);
                if (pixels->r > 128 && pixels->r <= 135)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels16++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data16 %d",numberOfRedPixels16);

                if (pixels->r >= 136 && pixels->r <= 143)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels17++;
                }

                NSLog( @"Red pixel data17 %d",numberOfRedPixels17);

                if (pixels->r >= 144 && pixels->r <=151)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels18++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data18 %d",numberOfRedPixels18);

                if (pixels->r >= 152 && pixels->r <=159 )
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels19++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data19 %d",numberOfRedPixels19);

                if (pixels->r >= 160 && pixels->r <= 167)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels20++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data20 %d",numberOfRedPixels20);

                if (pixels->r >= 168 && pixels->r <= 175)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels21++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data21 %d",numberOfRedPixels21);
                if (pixels->r >= 176 && pixels->r <= 199)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels22++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data22 %d",numberOfRedPixels22);

                if(pixels->r >= 184 && pixels->r <= 191)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels23++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data23 %d",numberOfRedPixels23);

                if (pixels->r >= 192 && pixels->r <= 199)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels24++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data24 %d",numberOfRedPixels24);

                if (pixels->r >= 200 && pixels->r <= 207)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels25++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data25 %d",numberOfRedPixels25);

                if (pixels->r >= 208 && pixels->r <= 215)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels26++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data26 %d",numberOfRedPixels26);

                if (pixels->r >= 216 && pixels->r <= 223)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels27++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data27 %d",numberOfRedPixels27);

                if (pixels->r >= 224 && pixels->r <= 231)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels28++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data28 %d",numberOfRedPixels28);

                if (pixels->r >= 232  && pixels->r <= 239)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels29++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data29 %d",numberOfRedPixels29);

                if (pixels->r >= 240 && pixels->r <= 247)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels30++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data30 %d",numberOfRedPixels30);

                if (pixels->r >= 248)
                {
                    numberOfRedPixels31++;
                }
                NSLog( @"Red pixel data31 %d",numberOfRedPixels31);
                pixels++;

                numberOfPixels--;
            }

            CGContextRelease(context);
        }

        free(pixels);
    }

    return 1;
}           

@end
```

My problem is I want skin Tone Pixel how it could be possible

Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Remember, there are *a lot* of skin tones.

Comment: did you find the skin tone exactly....?

Answer (score 0):

All this code is doing is determining the number of pixels that have red components within specific ranges.  If you just want to look for skin tone pixels, remove all the comparisons but one and change that from

```
if (pixels->r >= 192 && pixels->r <= 199)
```

to

```
if ( (pixels->r >= ? && pixels->r <= ?) && (pixels->g >= ? && pixels->g <= ?) && (pixels->b >= ? && pixels->b <= ?) )
```

where the question marks are placeholders for the actual value ranges for each of the three color components that will define skin tone in your application.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing now is binning the pixels based on the value of the red component, if you think of the colorspace you are basically dividing it up into rectangular pieces along the red axis.

To recognize skin tones you will need to do something similar, define a region in the colorspace that you think is skin colored and do a similar test for inclusion.  It will be a bit tricker though since I do not expect that it will be nice and rectangular.

That also totally ignores the problem of determining who's skin tone you are talking about, that is a whole different problem.

Comment: Especially if you are shooting pictures of Sean Paul or Oprah :D